# Dynamically allocate memory to an array in a separate function std::bad_alloc received

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

First of all I know that i can use `std::vector` instead of `arrays`, but I want to use arrays because I want to understand how one can allocate memory outside the declaration scope.

I want to pass the common_words array to a function and in that function I want to allocate some memory.

When i run my code I receive this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc

Here is the code:

```
void allocSpace(std::string *&common_words, int words_k)
{
     common_words = new std::string[words_k];   
}

int main(void)
{
    int words_k = 0, comma_k = 0;
    std::string *common_words;

    std::cout << "Enter the words to be ignored separated by \',\': " << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, words_list);

    comma_k = getCommaNumber(words_list); // returns 2 (const int value)
    words_k = comma_k + 1;

    allocSpace(common_words, words_k);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure of the value of `words_k`?  If you print it before you call `allocSpace`, qwhat do you get?

Comment: What about simply using a `std::vector<std::string>`? But what's the value of `words_k` when you call `new std::string[words_k]`? That's probably the reason why you're failing.

Comment: @NathanOliver I receive "1878006339" :((. You are right the problem is in `getCommaNumber` function.

Comment: Looks like you need to debug `getCommaNumber` then.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where is the declaration of `words_list`? Your example is not complete without it. Then again, to make the example minimal, maybe you want to remove all the lines that refer to `words_list`? A minimal example would probably skip the I/O and just call `allocSpace(common_words, 3);`.

Answer (score -2):

Edit.... So Here is an example and a image of kinda what is happening in memory.

```
int* allocateArray(int size){
    int *ptrArray = new int[size];
    return ptrArray;
```

So line by line. Define array and put in its arguments. For this we will have the size of the array. `int size` next we need to create the memory location and give it a pointer. `int *ptrArray = new int[size]` next we want to return the value of our pointer so basically the address it points too. `return ptrArray` Note how when we define the array we do int* to let it know that we will be returning the value of a pointer. And here is as super simple img of what this looks like in memory 
[image]

Also I removed the previous stuff I said to not make it a super long post and also because it was not relevant.

Comment: Thanks for answering but for me was important just to understand how I can dynamically allocate memory for one array in an external function.

Comment: Also note: I know the memory table is a super bad/simplified example but it gets in your head how to think about these things.